# Why do no programs run in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I recently got a new computer and reinstalled visual studio code but I haven't been able to run any of my files. The error has occurred with both python and C++, so I feel as though it is the IDE that is the problem. I have looked online and there are no straight answers as I have tried following some solutions which have resulted in different errors.
[image: Image of the error]

The error above comes up when I run (F5) a simple line of code in c++. Does anyone have a solution?
[image: launch.json file]

Thanks, Jacob

[EDIT]
For my python files to work I have to manually select 'Python: current file' but for c++ files they still have the same error.

[image: Image of run/debug]

Answer (score 0):

First step, uninstall python from this machine.

Second, reinstall and make sure that you check the box "add to path".

It's pretty easy to miss as it's a small box, and I missed it my first time installing python earlier in the year. [Here's the box you may have missed while installing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfzhD.png)

Comment: Thanks, thats fixed my python files but C++ still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

It could be your extensions.

I had a similar error message and simply updated all of my extensions and then my SDK. I was then able to run my code within the IDE. I was using VSCode for c++ and also updated my GCC compiler along with the extensions.

Also look into your computer's environment variables, if you have changed the %PATH variables it may be affecting your ability to run/compile programs.

Comment: I have reinstalled the extensions, python and visual studio code and the error is still the same :(
I edited the question so that you can see the run/debug problem